# Terraform dynamically generate strings using data sources output

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

Is there any way I can feed the Terraform data source output to another Terraform file as input

The scenario is, I have a terraform code to fetch the private IP addresses (here 3 IPs 10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3) for particular tags(here jenkins) using data source

```
data "aws_instances" "mytag" {
    filter {
        name = "tag:Application"
        values = ["jenkins"]
    }
}

output "output from aws" {
    value = data.aws_instances.mytag_private_ips
}
```

Whenever, I do the terraform apply, the    on the pattern section in the
below metric-filter code should be able to fetch the resultant IPs from the above code and make them available in the live state ( aws console )

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "test" {
    name = "test-metric-filter"
    pattern = "[w1,w2,w3,w4!=\"*<IP1>*\"&&w4!=\"*<IP2>*\"&&w4!=\"*<IP3>*\",w5=\"*admin*\"]"
    log_group_name = var.test_log_group_name

    metric_transformation {
      name ="test-metric-filter"
      namespace = "General"
    }
}
```

So, the final result of metric pattern in the aws console should be like below

```
[w1,w2,w3,w4!="*10.1.1.1*"&&w4!="*10.1.1.2*"&&w4!="*10.1.1.3*",w5="*admin*"]
```

The end goal is whenever if the new IPs are generated, it will get populated to pattern (in aws-console) without changing the metric-filter code.

Any help is appreciated, as I could not find any precise document on terraform allows us to dynamically generate strings using data sources

Comment: So little code why two files?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need two files for something this simple...
Here is what I would do:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_instances" "test" {
  filter {
    name   = "architecture"
    values = ["x86_64"]
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "test" {
  name    = "test-metric-filter"
  pattern = "[w1,w2,w3,w4!=\"*${data.aws_instances.test.private_ips[0]}*\",w5=\"*admin*\"]"
  log_group_name = "test_log_group_name"

  metric_transformation {
    name      = "test-metric-filter"
    namespace = "General"
    value     = 1
  }
}
```

And a terraform plan will show

```txt
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter.test will be created
  + resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "test" {
      + id             = (known after apply)
      + log_group_name = "test_log_group_name"
      + name           = "test-metric-filter"
      + pattern        = "[w1,w2,w3,w4!=\"*172.31.70.170*\",w5=\"*admin*\"]"

      + metric_transformation {
          + name      = "test-metric-filter"
          + namespace = "General"
          + unit      = "None"
          + value     = "1"
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Concatenating strings is easy: `"foo ${var.bar} 123"`
and on this case our private_ips is an array so we need the `[x]`

For more complex concatenations look into the format function:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/format.html

I did changed the filter to be able to test on my environment and also used a shorter pattern than yours, but that is the basis for what you need, just add more of make changes to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [string interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#interpolation) in Terraform.

I believe you would want to do the following:

```
pattern = "[w1,w2,w3,w4!=\"*${data.aws_instances.mytag.private_ips[0]}*\"&&w4!=\"*${data.aws_instances.mytag.private_ips[1]}*\"&&w4!=\"*${data.aws_instances.mytag.private_ips[2]}*\",w5=\"*admin*\"]"
```

I suggest being careful with this statement, because it will fail if you don't have at least 3 instances. You would want to have something dynamic instead.